# how concatenate two commands?

Tags: shell, awk, command

I need to concatenate two commands on shell, I'd have the path result and concatenate with the number of column in the first field.

**EX:**

```
#this gives me the path of my path directory like this: `/apps/ent/appli_ent/gen/dev/recep/ENTSMETA.20150824.txt`
find $REP_RECEP -name "*META*" -print
```

I'd take the result of this command and concatenate with this:

```
#this gives me the number of my colmuns field.
awk -F'|' '{print NF; exit}'
```

When I do this:

```
awk -F'|' '{print NF; exit}' find $REP_RECEP -name "*META*" -print
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: `awk -F'|' 'FNR==1 {print NF}' $(find $REP_RECEP -name "*META*" -print)`

Comment: @JJoao Thanks a lot , thats exactly what i want

Comment: @aminetabenyoussef note that JJoao's solution breaks if your file names contain spaces or any other strange characters.

Comment: @terdon, exactly , I had a file with spaces, and your method solved the problem . thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way, which can work with arbitrary file names, is to use `find`'s `-exec` option. This will run the specified command on every file/directory found by `find` (from `man find`):

```
       -exec command ;
          Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
          arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
          an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}'
          is replaced by the current file name being processed [...]
```

So, you can do:

```
find "$REP_RECEP" -name "*META*" -exec awk -F'|' '{print NF; exit}' {} \;
```

Comment: Or one requiring fewer invocations of `awk` and therefore faster `find "$REP_RECEP" -name "*META*" -exec awk -F'|' '{print NF; nextfile}' {} +`